# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: In Rest API JAVA

Tags: java, rest

I am Using a project1's class in another Rest API Project2 in Eclipse.
I have added that project1 to rest api project2's Build Path Still I am getting this Exception:

Code I have Used :

```
@Path("/studentreq/json")
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public Response requestBasicReport(Student stu) {
        OperationResult operationResult = new OperationResult();
        boolean responseFlag = false;
        try {
            if (operationResult.isSuccessful()) {
                responseFlag = true;
            } else {
                responseFlag = false;
                // send a message
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            responseFlag = false;
        } finally {
            // nullify objects
            if (responseFlag) {
                return Response.ok(stu).build(); //put the required object in ok(object)
            } else {
                return Response.serverError().build();
            }
        }
    }
```

Exception:

```
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.40 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/project/common/OperationResult</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Exception report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/project/common/OperationResult</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><p><b>exception</b> <pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/project/common/OperationResult
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:420)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
</pre></p><p><b>root cause</b> <pre>java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/project/common/OperationResult
    org.project.basil.service.ReportRequest.requestBasicReport(ReportRequest.java:131)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Comment: How did u set class path in eclipse. ? rightclick on project --> build path --> conifg build path --> add class folder --> select bin folder of project1.

Comment: @kaliva08 not working

Answer (score 1):

Problem Has been solved we have to add project to Properties--> Deployment Assembly--> ADD--> Project

Answer (score 0):

Adding one project to another project will help you just in the compilation but not in the exectuion. You need to have dependent class, maybe packaged as jar and then put them either in your webapp or your server lib directory. Make sure the web container where your application is deployed is able to find the classes, in short those should be on the classpath.

Comment: if we refer any project in eclipse to another in build path it resolves automatically in eclipse na

Comment: If I am not wrong - if you add a project to project's buildpath it auto-resolves the classpaths. Supporting this fact is my java console application which is running fine but its not working for jersey rest.

Comment: Problem Has been solved we have to add project to Properties--> Deployment Assembly--> ADD--> Project